# ffmpeg - connection refused

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm attempting to stream from a file, using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i video.webm -c copy -f webm rtmp://localhost:8090/stream
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TCP connection to localhost:8090 failed: Connection refused
```

This is the config file I'm using, which has the port, BindAddress, and ACL allow 127.0.0.1 already set. What's missing for this to be able to work?

http://ffmpeg.org/sample.html

Comment: You didn't provide very much information. I assume by "config file" you're referring to `ffserver`. You should provide the `ffmpeg` console output, the `ffserver` output, and the `ffserver` config file contents.

Comment: I thought I had included the link to the config file the first time, but there it is now.

Comment: That is the sample config file. Are you using that without modifying it?

Comment: Yes, it's unmodified.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179910/tcp-connection-refused-when-using-ffserver-ffmpeg

Comment: http://ffmpeg.org/sample.html link now broken. The full content of the file should be edited into the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you quickly just try to change your localhost references to 127.0.0.1 in your config file? If that helps, then you have an idea of the problem.

Comment: Yeah, that did it.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 15.10 ffmpeg 2.7.6, I needed to add to the default `/etc/ffserver.conf` file:

```
<Feed feed1.ffm>
    ACL allow 127.0.0.1
    ACL allow localhost
    ACL allow 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
</Feed>
```

*inside* the `Feed` element (there were other `ACL` lines, but for `Stream`).